# Why is eclipse not adding my strings to the resource file?

Tags: android, android-resources

Ok so I am working on an Android OS and I have followed the instructions and pulled down the source, plus setup eclipse properly. I have made a change in my strings.xml file in one of the framework projects. However, after I perform a make on the project that string does not get added to the appropriate resource file in out/target/common/. Hence my Eclipse is not picking up any new resource.

I have performed the following.

1.) A clean on the project.

2.) Completely delete the out so that everything would be rebuilt.

3.) Tested to make sure the build was actually pulling changes from that same project. Basically I added my string directly to the project instead of using a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out the problem. If you are working on the OS source and you want to add a string to the string.xml file you MUST also add the following line of code to your public.xml file that exists inside your values folder.

```
<java-symbol type="string" name="my_string_resource_name" /> <!--In public.xml-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out following points they may work...

1. Check all activities if `import android.R;`is imported in any java file remove that import statement.
2. Then delete R.java file.

**It may works, just check**

Comment: Yeah I got nothing. I went through and removed all the android.R's which were in different packages (not the one I was editing) and that really solved nothing. It is almost as if there is a third element that make is using to generate the R class and thats the one im not updating.